# What is the difference between the template statement and event handler?

Tags: angular, events, event-handling

Do we e call  `print($event)` in `<p (click)=”print($event)”>`, a template statement or an event handler?.

Comment: The discussion here should clarify: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#binding-to-user-input-events The left side is event binding. The right side is a template statement that provides the event handler.